# CSS: how to snap buttons to side of images

Tags: css, button, layout, image-gallery

I have created a image gallery in css with next and prev buttons. The images vary in height and length, is there a property or attribute I am missing that will "snap" the buttons to the middle of each side of the image regardless of size?

If I have just phrased my question poorly I apologise, thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Can you include a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what exactly you're asking and what isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) for this. This is switched on for an element by the CSS:

```
display: flex;
```

I've created a fuller example using flexbox at https://jsfiddle.net/dacmo/hv8tk6dy/8/ that does what I believe you're describing.

Comment: Edit: Updated URL to fiddle.